# After splitting the code into functions it doesn't work properly. C programming

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to split this small code into functions, but I'm having trouble, the code is supposed to show if the words are anagrams or no. If I put everything into main, it works perfectly, but now that I have spitted it into functions it shows that all words are not anagrams.

I suppose that the problem is in the getWords function, in the loops where it get words. You guys will probably know where I screwed up. Thanks in advance. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void getWords(char *first,char *second,int *alphabet)
{
    int i = 0, sum = 0;
    printf("Enter the first word: ");
    do
    {
    //I think the problem is somewhere under here
    first[i] = getchar();
    if(isalpha(first[i]))
    alphabet[toupper(first[i]) - 'A'] += 1 ;
    i++;

    }while(first[i - 1] != '\n');

printf("Enter the second word: ");
i = 0;
do
{
    //and here
    second[i] = getchar();

    if(isalpha(second[i]))
    {
        alphabet[toupper(second[i]) - 'A'] -= 1;
    }
    i++;

}while(second[i - 1] != '\n');

}


void checksForAnagrams(int sum, int alphabet[26])
{
    int i;

for(i = 0; i <= 26 - 1; i++)
    {
        sum += alphabet[i];
    }
    if (sum == 0)
        printf("Anagrams\n");
    if (sum != 0)
        printf("Not anagrams\n");
 }


int main()
{

    int alphabet[26] = {0}, sum = 0;
    char first[20], second[20];

    getWords(&first[20], &second[20], &alphabet[26]);
    checksForAnagrams(sum, &alphabet[26]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in the debugger?  SO is not a replacements for learning proper debug skills.

Comment: yeah, no warnings no errors

Comment: `&first[20]` doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: 'getWords(&first[20], &second[20], &alphabet[26]);' these arguments point to the end of the arrays:(

Comment: i think the function call should be just `getWords(first, second, alphabet)` since all of them are pointers. Also, when you call `first[20]`you are trying to get the 20th value of the array, which doesnt exist.

Comment: @TacoCat The debugger is not the same thing as the compiler. A debugger with a good GUI should help.

Comment: Thank you for the critique, i found my mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
char *first = &first[20];
```

Now `first` points to the last+1 element of the array which is not what you want fix it. The valid index for the array `first` is `0 - 19`

```
getWords(first, second, alphabet);
```

Comment: `first[19]` is the last element of the array.